# Before action with inline method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying this in my controller

```
before_action { authorize @user }, except: [:index]
```

and getting the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) before_action { authorize @user }, except: [:index]
                                                                                                    ^
```

When I use just

```
before_action { authorize @user }
```

It works fine. My question is how do I add an `except:` clause to this line?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also specify blocks with do...end

```
   before_action except: [:index] do
      authorize @user
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do:

```
before_action except: [:index] { authorize @user }
```

Or with array if you will need it, example:

```
before_action except: [:index, :edit] { authorize @user }
```

Comment: With Ruby >= 2.5.0 you'll need to do: `before_action(except: [:index, :edit]) { authorize @user }`