# Rails 7 - How to run a before action with inline code only for an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 7.1 with Ruby 3.2.2, what's the correct syntax to run a `before_action` filter with inline code only for a specific action?

I have tried everything suggested in [Before action with inline method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322685/before-action-with-inline-method), but I always get an error.

```
before_action only: :destroy, { authorize!(with: AllowAllPolicy) }
before_action only: [:destroy], { authorize!(with: AllowAllPolicy) }
before_action { authorize!(with: AllowAllPolicy) }, only: :destroy
before_action { authorize!(with: AllowAllPolicy) }, only: [:destroy]
before_action { authorize!(with: AllowAllPolicy), only: :destroy }
before_action { authorize!(with: AllowAllPolicy), only: [:destroy] }
before_action(only: :destroy, { authorize!(with: AllowAllPolicy) })
before_action(only: [:destroy], { authorize!(with: AllowAllPolicy) })
```

Comment: `before_action(only: :destroy) { authorize!(with: AllowAllPolicy) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close. Your first option without the comma is what you're after, with a small tweak to resolve the precedence issue, so either:

```rb
before_action(only: :destroy) { authorize!(with: AllowAllPolicy) }

## or

before_action only: :destroy do
  authorize!(with: AllowAllPolicy)
end
```